# Scala generic function that converts string to generic type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a function that should find command-line parameter with it's value and return converted to type `P`:

```
def parameter[P](name: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[P]): P = {

    val paramName = s"--$name"

    args.sliding(2, 2).toList.collectFirst {
      case Array(`paramName`, param: String) => {
        // if P is Int => param.toInt
        // if P is Double => param.toDouble
      }
    }.get
  }
```

How do I do that? I've found that `ClassTag` is a way to go, but can't figure out how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [Travis'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518153/4727702) and [ColOfAbRiX's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518188/4727702) answers are working solutions. But as Travis noted, they are not *typesafe*.

Here is the solution I ended up with (see [Scala Type Classes 101: Introduction](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/type-classes-101-introduction)):

Define **implicit converters** for types you need:

```
trait StringConverter[P] {
  def convert(a: String): P
}

implicit val string2string = new StringConverter[String] {
  def convert(a: String): String = a
}
implicit val string2double = new StringConverter[Double] {
  def convert(a: String): Double = a.toDouble
}
implicit val string2int = new StringConverter[Int] {
  def convert(a: String): Int = a.toInt
}
implicit val string2long = new StringConverter[Long] {
  def convert(a: String): Long = a.toLong
}
implicit val string2bool = new StringConverter[Boolean] {
  def convert(a: String): Boolean = a.toBoolean
}
```

And then use them as follows:

```
def parameter[P](name: String)(implicit converter: StringConverter[P]): P = {
  val paramName = s"--$name"

  val res = args.sliding(2, 2).toList.collectFirst {
    case Array(`paramName`, param: String) => converter.convert(param)
  }

  res.get
}
```

Accepting my answer as it is (IMHO) cleaner and typesafe - it will not compile if you don't define conversion for one or more types that you use (`ClassTag` solution would compile and fail at runtime).

*Comments, corrections, suggestions are greatly appreciated.*

Comment: I like this one. I'm still fairly new to Scala

Answer (score 6):

You can compare the class tag to tags for the types you want to match:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def parameter[P](args: Array[String], name: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[P]): P = {
  val paramName = s"--$name"

  args.sliding(2, 2).toList.collectFirst {
    case Array(`paramName`, param: String) => (
      if (tag == classTag[Double]) {
        param.toDouble
      } else if (tag == classTag[Int]) {
        param.toInt
      } // and so on...
    ).asInstanceOf[P]
  }.get
}
```

You could also use pattern matching or whatever, of course. It works as expected:

```
scala> parameter[Int](Array("--foo", "123"), "foo")
res0: Int = 123

scala> parameter[Double](Array("--foo", "123"), "foo")
res1: Double = 123.0
```

There are lots of downsides to this approach, though—you have to know all the types you want to parse in the definition of `parameter`, etc.—and you're probably better off with a proper type class specifically designed for the kind of parsing you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That works for me. Would accept the answer from @ColOfAbRiX as it looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych [I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331849/4111404) a similar question a few weeks ago, I used a similar approach as Travis. But, I used **Options** and the **ClassTag**'s `unapply` method to ensure everything was _typesafe_ - you may gave it a look, it may help you ;) - Anyways, as Travis already said _(and as Tim said in that post)_, is always better to create your own typeclass for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Few resources that can help you:

- https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html and
- https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20
- https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-pattern-match-generic-parameter-type-in-Scala

Example from one of the links:

```
scala>   val StringClass = classTag[String]
scala>   val IntClass = classTag[Int]
scala>   def typeList[T](list: List[T])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) =
          tag match {
            case StringClass => "It's a String!"
            case IntClass => "It's an Integer."
            case _ => "It's something else entirely"
          }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. One quick question: where do you import `StringClass`, `IntClass`,... from?

Comment: First line of the code: `val StringClass = classTag[String]` :)

Comment: I'm blind or something:) Thanks a lot!